# Focusing electricity through air

Tags: voltage, air

Everyone knows there exist such things as a tesla coils. Those tesla coils have high voltage and since air conducts electricity bad, with high voltage it is still conducting it. My questions are: is there some kind of probability(which could be calculated), that an electrical bolt travels to a specific direction(without any metal devices around)? And the main question is: Would it somehow be possible to focus that energy and shoot it straight, without any huge direction changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Would it somehow be possible to focus that energy and shoot it straight, without any huge direction changes?**

This is essentially what a [cathode ray tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_ray_tube) does.

> The cathode ray tube (CRT) is a vacuum tube that contains one or more electron guns and a phosphorescent screen, and is used to display images.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boGhz.png) It modulates, accelerates, and deflects electron beam(s) onto the screen

[image]

2. Electron beams
3. Focusing coils

However it does need a near vacuum and it does need an electric field and other equipment which typically involve the presence of metal objects nearby.

You may also enjoy reading about [electrolasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolaser)

> An electrolaser is a type of electroshock weapon that is also a directed-energy weapon. It uses lasers to form an electrically conductive laser-induced plasma channel (LIPC). A fraction of a second later, a powerful electric current is sent down this plasma channel and delivered to the target, thus functioning overall as a large-scale, high energy, long-distance version of the Taser electroshock gun.

Comment: This subject has a lack of information on the internet. Specificaly using high voltage to shoot .Electrolaser was just what i needed, every and each detail. Thank you very much. If you have something more to this subject, i'd be glad to read it.